# Disable Cognito UI, but still use oauth

Tags: oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have a Cognito user pool that supports Cognito, Facebook, and Google users, plus a SAML provider. I expect that we will add more SAML providers in the future.

I also have a web application using Amplify for authentication. Cognito users log in via the application interface, and Google and Facebook users are sent to those sites via `Auth.federatedSignIn`. SAML users are sent to a Cognito domain, and thence redirected to whatever URL the third-party provider uses. (The appropriate `idp_identifier` is derived from the user's email address.)

The problem is that if a user tries to sign in via SAML, but they don't have a valid account for that, so that their derived `idp_identifier` doesn't match an existing one, then they will see the Cognito UI. Instead, I would like for authentication to fail. Basically, the Cognito domain should only function for users with a known `idp_identifier`, and no one should ever be able to see the Cognito UI.

Can this be done, or would authentication have to be set up differently?